# The website of Chinese bing.com cannot fetch its wallpaper

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bing

The website `https://cn.bing.com/?mkt=zh-CN` always fail to fetch wallpaper (ip in China), while the global bing website `https://www.bing.com/` works well (when my ip switech to Singapore).

My browser infomation: Google Chrome, version: `110.0.5481.178 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, whithout any extension.

How can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8fXN.jpg)

I block all my extensions, but no work.

I thinks the web itself has some problems, so do anybody work for bing(CHN) or bing(global) know what is happen? THX